# C# Accessing a property within a property?

Tags: c#, properties

I'm trying to pass some tests in the Exercism C# exercise 'weighing machine' which uses properties. I have these properties:

```
using System;
enum Units
{
   Pounds,
   Kilograms
}

class WeighingMachine
{
    private decimal inputWeight;
    public decimal InputWeight
    {
        get { return inputWeight; }
        set { if (value >= 0)
                inputWeight = value;
            else throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }

    private decimal displayWeight;
    public decimal DisplayWeight
    {
        get
        { return displayWeight; }
        set
        {
            displayWeight = InputWeight - TareAdjustment;
            if (displayWeight <= 0)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
    }

    private decimal _pounds;
   
    public USWeight USDisplayWeight
    {
        get { return _pounds; }
        set { _pounds = new USWeight(InputWeight).Pounds; }
    }

    public decimal TareAdjustment { private get; set; }

    public int Units
    { get; set; }
}

    struct USWeight
    {
        public USWeight(decimal weightInPounds)
        {
            Pounds = (int)weightInPounds;
            Ounces = (weightInPounds - Pounds)*16;
        }
    
        public int Pounds { get; set; }

        public decimal Ounces { get; set; }
    }
```

My stumbling block is the tests:

```
[Fact]
public void Get_us_display_weight_pounds()
{
    var wm = new WeighingMachine();
    wm.InputWeight = 60m;
    Assert.Equal(132, wm.USDisplayWeight.Pounds);
}
```

I can't get my head around how the test is asking for wm.USDisplayWeight.Pounds  - how is the .Pounds accessed on the end? it's like there is a property set within the USDisplayWeight property, but that's not possible is it? I can't make the compiler stop complaining about the .Pounds - I get ''decimal' does not contain a definition for 'Pounds' and no accessible extension method 'Pounds' accepting a first argument of type 'decimal' could be found.

I'm sure it's a simple thing that I'm overlooking here, but I would appreciate any help at all.

Comment: Take a look at the definition of `USDisplayWeight`. It's of type `decimal`, not `USWeight`. That's why you are getting the error. Properties don't need backing fields; you can write any code you want.  Make the `USDisplayWeight` getter simply return the `DisplayWeight` multiplied by a conversion factor. Similarly, have the setter update the USDisplayWeight after conversion.  By having two weight fields, you risk having something weigh both 10 kg and 8 lb.

Comment: Note that your `DisplayWeight` setter doesn't use the value it's provided - that's a bit of a red flag. You should consider just putting the logic in the setter, and making it a read-only property. (Ditto `USDisplayWeight`.)

Comment: Thanks Flydog57, using USWeight for the property type has removed the error. @Jon Skeet, I'm not sure I understand your comment about DisplayWeight. - it sets the value from two other property values, also I thought I had all the logic in the setter. it seems to pass the first test:
`
    [Fact]
    public void Set_weight_and_get_weight()
    {
        var wm = new WeighingMachine();
        wm.InputWeight = 60m;
        Assert.Equal(60m, wm.InputWeight, precision: 3);
    }
`

Comment: @RonCitrus: The point is that someone can write `wm.DisplayWeight = 15m`; and the value being assigned (15) is ignored completely. You don't need the field or anything - just a getter which computes the result from the other properties: `public decimal DisplayWeight => InputWeight - TareAdjustment;`.

Comment: @Jon Skeet, of course. Thanks